# Symfony manually validate entity with relation

Tags: php, validation, symfony, entity, relation

I want to validate a User entity with custom constraint & validator. So far it's working when triggered by form workflow, but if I trigger it manually, I loose one relation I setup before calling validation :

UserController :

```
$user = new User();
$user->setRoles($roles);
$user->setSite($site);
...

$violations = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($user);
```

User entity with Site relation :

```
   /**
     * @var Site the site linked to the entity
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LCH\MultisiteBundle\Entity\Site", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $site;
```

Validator :

```
public function validate($user, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $email = $user->getEmail();

        // $site var is null while other "direct fields are filled
        $site = $user->getSite();
        $roles = $user->getRoles();
        $username = $user->getUsername();
```

How can I manually validate this entity using preceeding set relation?

Comment: How do you obtain the $site, from a repository?

Comment: Yes, with a find($id) built-in method, with $id provided by a type in form. Do you think about an EntityManager scope problem?

Comment: You can try to persist your user before validating

Answer (score 0):

My problem found its origin in Symfony2 form validation structure. : as $form->handleRequest($request) indeed validates form, all hooked validators (groups, custom constrains and callbacks) are triggered.

My $site was null because validator was fired long before I set up my $user->site attribute...

```
// sumbit in this method trigger validation too early in my needs
$form->handleRequest($request);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && !$isAjax) {
    // custom processes to decide what to create
    ...
    // Here is the user creation 
    $user->setRoles($roles);
    $user->setSite($site);
    ...
    // And the check
    $violations = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($user);
}
```

The solution here lied in [disabling validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation) in the main type. Doing so, $user is fully passed to validator.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => false,
        ));
    }
```

The main drawback with this system is that I have to manually trigger validation for this very type in all interactions, but this type is complex enough to make sense here.